# Is their a cleaner way to write a bank account app using java

Tags: java

Hello guy i created a small bank system on which am practising classes, constructor and also getter setter method, i thought of using loop in the banking class but i see no use is their a better to write such code also i will like to ask if it okay to have a system.out println in either getter or setter?

```
   public class Banking {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        private int accountNumber;
        private double balance;
        private double moneyWithDrawl;


        private String customerName;
        private String email;
        private String phoneNumber;
        public Banking() 
        {

        }
        public Banking(int accountNumber,double balance, String customerName,
                String email, String phoneNumber) 
        {
            this.accountNumber=accountNumber;
            this.balance=balance;
            this.customerName= "Welcome " +customerName;
            this.email=email;
            this.phoneNumber=phoneNumber;
        }
        public void setAccountNumber(int accountNumber) 
        {
            this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        }
        public void setCustomerName(String customerName) 
        {
            this.customerName=customerName;
        }
        public void setEmail(String email) 
        {
            this.email=email;
        }
        public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) 
        {
            this.phoneNumber= phoneNumber;
        }
        public void setWithdrawal(double withDrawal) 
        {   
            this.moneyWithDrawl = withDrawal;
            if (this.moneyWithDrawl > this.balance) {
                System.out.println("Not enough fund");
            }
            else if (moneyWithDrawl == 0){
            System.out.println("Cant WithDrawal " + 0);
            }
            else if (this.balance >= this.moneyWithDrawl) {
                System.out.println("Amount withDrawn is "+ moneyWithDrawl+ " New total is " + (this.balance-=this.moneyWithDrawl));
            }
        }

        public void setDeposit(double deposit) 
        {
            this.balance += deposit;
            System.out.println("The amount of " + deposit + " Been added New balance is " + balance);
        }

        public int getAccountNumber() 
        {

            return this.rnd.nextInt(accountNumber);
        }
        public String getCustomerName() 
        {
            return this.customerName;
        }
        public String getEmail() 
        {
            return this.email;
        }
        public String getPhoneNumber() 
        {
            return this.phoneNumber;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by cleaner?

Comment: use pojo concept.

Comment: With lesser typing also what is meant by pojo concept?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like Procedural Programming (like programming in C language) instead of Object Oriented.

There is only one class defined here, `Banking`, which is basically the whole program. Since this is Java you had to define at least one class because nothing exists outside of one.

You could use Object Oriented Programming to your advantage. You could for example structure your data in various objects and then rewrite a **"cleaner"** program.

For example you could wrap that data

```java
private int accountNumber;
private double balance;
private double moneyWithDrawl;
```

into its own class, say **Account**.

```java
class Account{
    private int number;
    double balance;

    Account(int number, double balance){
        this.number=number;
        this.balance=balance;
    }

    public void withdraw(double amount){
        // withdrawing logic here
    }

    public void insert(double amount){
        // logic
    }
}
```

Then you could do the same with this data over here...

```java
private String customerName;
private String email;
private String phoneNumber;
```

Wrap that in a **Customer class** which apart from above it could contain `Account` data as well!

```java
class Customer{
    public String name, email, phoneNumber;
    public Account account;

    Customer(String name, String email, String phoneNumber){
        this.name=name;
        this.email=email;
        this.phoneNumber;
    }

    Customer(String name, String email, String phoneNumber, Account account){
        this(name,email,phoneNumber);
        this.account=account;
    }
}
```

Now you can create your program and interact with those objects. For example

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // Create a customer
  Account acc = new Account(131313, 1000);
  Customer cust = new Customer("Nick", "nick@mail.com","+46 320 000", acc);

  // make him withdraw 100$, etc...
  cust.account.withdraw(100);
}
```

Comment: By pressing the ✔ on the question (even upvoting when you thing the answer was usefull)